# mod_rewrite point subdomain to subfolder (which contains more mod_rewrite rules)

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite

mod_rewrite point subdomain to subfolder (which contains more mod_rewrite rules)

After some work I came up with this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)  /home/mydomain/public_html/wildcard/%1/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that the rules in .htaccess file in /home/mydomain/public_html/wildcard/subdomain/ are not evaluated.

Comment: Do you have a lots of subdomain? Are they dynamic (like username.domain.com)? or more static like (english.domain.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` line looks wrong.

The second part of the `RewriteRule` should be the URL, not the path, of the location you want to rewrite to.

So in your case, maybe you want to try changing the RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule (.*) wildcard/%1/$1 [L]
```